# Can I use Simple HTML tags instead of struts2 tags?

Tags: html, struts2

There's a strange requirement where I need to get server side data on page load using only html tags.

I have following field in Struts 2 action

```
private String myData; //with getter and setter.
...
myData = "myValue";
....
```

and to bind it with text field in jsp, I usually write

```
<s:textfield name="myData"></s:textfield>
```

When result is dispatched to jsp, Struts2 renders it something like this

```
<input type="text" name="myData" value="myValue"></input>
```

But when I write

```
<input type="text" name="myData"></input>
```

It does not bring any value with it.

Can I achieve this without using strut2 tags, scriptlets, or any such server side thing in jsp?

Comment: Yes you can use <input type="text" name="myData"/>. It does get value on Action Class. I don't know why it is not working for you. s:textfield has extra few purposes such as to display validation error message

Comment: @Muhammad Bilal Mirza: you are free to use that and if you want to bind the value from Value-stack to the HTML tags can use build in support for JSTL like `<input type="text" name="myData" value="${myValue}"></input>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the `value` attribute in your tag... Any server programming language renders thier tag as html tags.

Comment: is right, Thanks for him. Struts uses free marker templates to render tags to html. I have seen 'simple' templates from strtuts2-core-2.x.y.jar/templates/simple. These templates clearly show the rendering of value attribute.